# Unable to remove registy keys during uninstall in WIX Installer

Tags: wix, wix3.8

The registry key values are not removing during uninstall the MSI.

Below is the code sample to add values to registry.
I am using **NeverOverwrite ="yes" Permanent="yes"** options for component because the registry values should not override during upgrade.

```
<Component Id="DFService_Registry" Guid="B4F1008F-1CF2-4170-94A5-2466AB15E145" Win64="yes" Directory="DFServicesDir" NeverOverwrite ="yes" Permanent="yes">

      <Condition><![CDATA[INSTALL_DFSERVICES=1 AND (NOT OLDER_VERSION_FOUND)]]></Condition>
      <!--Win64="yes"-->
      <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key='SOFTWARE\VALUEMOMENTUM\DEALFOUNDRY\DealFoundryServices' Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DfServicesInstalled" Value="Yes">
          <![CDATA[NOT OLDER_VERSION_FOUND]]>
        </RegistryValue>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DfServicesWebApplicationName" Value="[DFSERVICES_WEBAPPLICATIONNAME]">
          <![CDATA[NOT OLDER_VERSION_FOUND]]>
        </RegistryValue>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DfServicesPortNumber" Value="[DFSERVICES_PORTNUMBER]">
          <![CDATA[NOT OLDER_VERSION_FOUND]]>
        </RegistryValue>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DfServicesInstallDir" Value="[INSTALLDFSERVICES_DIR]">
          <![CDATA[NOT OLDER_VERSION_FOUND]]>
        </RegistryValue>
      </RegistryKey>

    </Component>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

With the setting permanent="yes" the registrykeys will not deleted during uninstallation. Use permanent="No".

Comment: or just remove the permanent attribute entirely since the default behavior will be to remove the reg keys on uninstall

Comment: i made the change but still the keys are not removing.